# Join 50 millions query one to one row

Tags: sql, request

I have two tables having 50 million unique rows each.

Row number from one table corresponds to row number in the second table.

**i.e** 
1st row  in the 1st table joins with 1st row in the second table, 2nd row in first table joins with 2nd row in the second table and so on. Doing inner join is costly.

It takes more than 5 hours on clusters. Is there an efficient way to do this in `SQL`?

Comment: Unless you're doing something particularly weird it's unlikely you can improve upon a simple join - that being said actually seeing the query would help! It's much more likely that the tables are not indexed properly or that the indicies are out of date. What does your execution plan tell you?

Comment: Inner join is efficient, if you have the right indexes - what does your schema look like? A 50 million row join should not take 5 hours to query - what are you retrieving? What indexes are present?

Comment: Vertical partitioning should be considered carefully, because analyzing data from multiple partitions requires queries that join the tables. Vertical partitioning also could affect performance if partitions are very large. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178148%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: What RDBMS are you using -- MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server, etc.? Please add it to the tags.

Comment: Schema for both tables is <query1, query2, similarity>. I am taking inner join on table1.query1 == table2.query1 AND table1.query2== table2.query2. Note that in both the tables, correspodning <query1, query2> aligns in the same row no. My tables are distributed across cluster nodes and I'm using COSMOS(HDFS like system). Taking inner join is costly because its gonna search for 50 million record in the other table to find a match for 1 record in the other table. So effectivly, it cost me O(n^2) operations where n=50 million. Also note that i'll be joining 5 such tables.

Answer (score 2):

To start with: tables are just sets. So the row number of a record can be considered pure coincidence. You must not join two tables based on row numbers. So you would join on IDs rather than on row numbers.

There is nothing more efficient than a simple inner join. As the whole tables must be read, you might not even gain anything from indexes (but as we are talking of IDs, there will be indexes anyhow, so nothing we must ponder on).

Depending on the DBMS you may be able to parallelize the query. In Oracle for example you would use a hint such as `/*+ parallel( tablename , parallel_factor ) */`.

Comment: hi, Plz see the issues in using inner join in my comments above this post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to sort both tables by rows (if isnt sorted),
then use normal SELECT (maybe you could use LIMIT to get it part by part) for both tables and
data connect line by line wherever you want

Comment: your solution seems joining tables in parts as one to one matching is required. Let me try this. Thanks.